# Android 65k multidex issue for android system application

Tags: android, android-multidex

Developing an system application which works with multiple libraries and aar files resulting application get the Multidex 65k issue which is reported by many developers working on Android studio . 
In my case as am working on android system build environment not sure how to enable the multidex option ?

Have extended the Application and added MultiDex.install(this); which is making no difference for the compilation resulting

trouble writing output: Too many method references: 156862; max is 65536.
You may try using --multi-dex option.

Not able to find any reference to work on the system build for this kind of issue .

Any pointers on this will be helpful

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for response . The issue am facing is related to android system app development not in the Android Studio . Have already applied the shared comments in the Android studio app development where i dont see the multidex error . But the issue is seen in Android system development as we dont have gradle files in this development environment . Let me know if any clarification required ?

Answer (score 2):

Update in your gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
  ..............

multiDexEnabled true


}
```

dexOptions should add..

```
dexOptions {
   //incremental = true;
preDexLibraries = false
javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
 }
```

dependency add

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Also In Your AndroidManifest.xml add this lines android:name

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
>
```

Comment: `preDexLibraries=false` alone did it in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Idea is if apk method is > 64K, then we break it to have multiple dex files.

In **build.gradle**

```
android {

    defaultConfig {

        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  // Add this dependency 
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Hope this helps.

Reference: [Android Dev](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can visit [Configure Apps with Over 64K Methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) for details.

Here some excerpt from it:

Setting up your app development project to use a multidex configuration requires that you make a few modifications to your app development project. In particular you need to perform the following steps:

- Change your Gradle build configuration to enable multidex
- Modify your manifest to reference the MultiDexApplication class

Modify the module-level build.gradle file configuration to include the support library and enable multidex output, as shown in the following code snippet:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

In your manifest add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

---

#### UPDATE

If you have included Google Play Service library, instead using:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

Try to only use what you really need. Something like this:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0 // only need ads
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0 // only need gcm
```

Read more at [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Comment: Thanks for response . The issue am facing is related to android system app development not in the Android Studio . Have already applied the shared comments in the Android studio app development where i dont see the multidex error . But the issue is seen in Android system development as we dont have gradle files in this development environment . Let me know if any clarification required ?

Comment: Can you explain your `But the issue is seen in Android system development as we dont have gradle files in this development environment ` words?. Is this means that you didn't use gradle?

Comment: What i mean by 'Android system development ' is download the code through repo sync commands - https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html , where complete OS source is downloaded . Am working on application to be included in this environment . Their is no GRADLE is these complete source code . Hope am able explain issue clearly now wrt android system environment . Not using Android Studio IDE for development .